# Grails 3.0 How to use Javascript in GSP's?

Tags: javascript, grails-3.0

The documentation says, that <[r:script](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/script.html)> is the right way to do this, but this is part of the [Resources Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources), which is not available in Grails 3.0, so I think in a single GSP the right way to use Javascript is  at the end of the `<body>` with the <[g:javascript](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html)>-tag.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<asset:javascript src="example.js" />` at the bottom of a GSP file.

However, SiteMesh inserts the body where `<g:layoutBody />` is in the layout GSP, so there could end up being some other tags between `<script>` and the end of the `<body>`.  It would be cleaner to create a separate layout GSP.

Also, be sure to **not** include `example.js` in `application.js` or else the special js file will end up on every page by default.  One option is to create an `assets/javascripts/public` folder for everything else.

**grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require_tree ./public
```